# Error trapping on the Response.Redirect

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

We are using the `Response.Redirect` to send users to a web site to take a questionnaire.  We have a database that stores information about the user's eligibility to take a survey and if they are eligible, a 'Take Survey' button appears on their home page and a variable stores the URL for the Survey.

On the `TakeSurvey_Click` event, the code originally the following:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Response.Redirect(TheURL);
```

Pretty straight forward and worked great for years.  Recently, we have changed the web site to which the user was being redirected.  There have been no issues for many thousands of users; however, for a reasonably significant group (2-3%), nothing happens when they press the 'Take Survey' button.

I am reasonably certain after searching the internet, that I have tried all of the recommended methods for handling this situation, but none really does what I want.  What I would like to happen is, that if the Take Survey doesn't send the user to the link (BTW, we have checked the link being generated for the non-working links, and they are good links), I want an informational page to appear telling them that we are having issues and if they could send us some information about their environment, it would be useful in fixing the issue.  Seems simple enough, but no matter what I try, I either can't get the page to not display, or, if I use the override and send a false, it never displays and never redirects.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Redirect` sends a "302 Moved" response to the browser. The browser is responsible for navigating to the destination URL.

Thus, once you've issued the `Response.Redirect`, it's out of your hands and there is no easy way to detect that the browser has not successfully navigated to your chosen URL.

Now, there are a few different ways (that I can think of do deal with this):

- You might be able to set `document.location` from client-side JavaScript.
- The page that issues the redirect could refresh itself periodically (using JavaScript or `meta refresh`). If it finds itself still on the same page after it should have gone somewhere else, then it can issue a warning.
- Or, more simply, the page that issues the redirect could just have instructions stating "We're sending you to take the survey. If, after 30 seconds, you're still looking at this message, something went wrong.".